# Verb for telling the oath

Tags: verbs

I had the honour to "say" the oath in our graduation ceremony, since I was 1st in the rank. Now, I want to include that in my [CV](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/cv/) that information. What verb should I use?

"Told the oath in graduation ceremony", is what I thought, but the verb does not sound right, does it?

In the dictionary, I found the verb *take*, which is not what I want, because every student actually takes the oath, but only the top one "tells" it.

---

***Recite*** and ***administer*** are best (IMHO) words suggested in the comments. Either you may argue for one of them over the other, or suggest something else.

Comment: I did search on a dictionary, but I am not sure what to search for, so I couldn't find anything good @MarvMills. Maybe because I am Greek, I do not understand what you mean by a thesaurus.

Comment: [ODO on *oath*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/oath) shows *take* and *swear* are commonly used. Please include your research in the question.

Comment: I did now @AndrewLeach, but my question is closed. However, the answer lies in Marv's comment. Thanks for the thesaurus too, it's really a thesaurus! ;)

Comment: The [Ozdic Collocation Dictionary](http://www.ozdic.com/collocation-dictionary/oath) is the first place to look.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thanks for the link, however Marv's suggestion seems to be the best and could also be an answer IMHO. And yes, thesauros is what I had in mind about the site! :) Thanks again.

Comment: I would further suggest *deliver* or (per Ozdic) *administer.*

Comment: As I'm sure Marv would / will agree, a thesaurus doesn't give you which member of a set of synonyms (say verbs) is usually paired with a given noun say. For collocations (idiomatic pairings), you usually need a dictionary of collocations.

Comment: I did not know that @EdwinAshworth. Anyway, my question is closed now. Thanks Brian for the suugestions!

Comment: @gsamaras "On hold" is not the same as "Closed". Now that you have included your research and more on the circumstances [where you were the spokesman for the whole group], it can be re-opened. You might want to enhance the question if you want to ask about *deliver* or *administer* from the comments.

Comment: Oh @AndrewLeach, sorry, I wasn't aware of that! Thanks, I will edit my question right away!

Comment: After your much-needed edit, it is clear that a thesaurus (synonyms for say / tell) _was_ the correct first port of call. [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=said+the+oath%2Ctold+the+oath%2Crecited+the+oath%2Cenunciated+the+oath&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csaid%20the%20oath%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crecited%20the%20oath%3B%2Cc0) (said the oath,told the oath,recited the oath,enunciated the oath) might have been the next.

Comment: In taking the oath at the Canadian citizenship ceremony, you repeat the oath after it has been READ by the official clerk. You could say something like "first reader of the oath"

Comment: Edwin, your comments actually made the question better! @P.Obertelli, if I am to use something different than a verb, then "spokesman" in Edwin's comment seems nice.

Comment: It would be good too @MarvMills. The only thing that bothers me with this is that the oath is taken by me too, not only by the other students.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your **swear** an oath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use ['recite'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/recite?s=t)

> **verb (used with object), recited, reciting.**
>
> 1 to repeat the words of, as from memory, especially in a formal manner: 
>   to recite a lesson
>
> 2 to repeat (a piece of poetry or prose) before an audience, as for entertainment
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

...or perhaps ['proclaim'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/proclaim?s=t) if the occasion is ceremonial.

> **verb (used with object)**
>
> 1 to announce or declare in an official or formal manner: 
>   to proclaim war
>
> 2 to announce or declare in an open or ostentatious way: 
>   to proclaim one's opinions
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are *leading* the oath.  Sort of like *administer*, but it is clearer that you are taking the oath, too.

Comment: That's a useful answer too, +1.

Answer (score 3):

As someone who has read a lot of CVs, I have to say that I would be puzzled by this entry about the oath.  Unless you are sure that your audience will understand what an honor this is, I suggest that you say: "Graduated first in my class at X".  (I'm not suggesting you say you were the valedictorian, because it seems clear from your post that you did not deliver a valedictory address.)  It is a good idea to have several CVs, each geared to the job you are applying for or the person who will be reading it.  This is in no way dishonest, and is common among savvy job-seekers.  This isn't a technical answer, but I hope it is a helpful one.

["Valedictorian is an academic title used in the USA, Canada, Costa Rica and the Philippines for the student who delivers the closing or farewell statement at a graduation ceremony (called a valedictory). The chosen valedictorian is usually the student with the highest ranking among his/her graduating class."]

Comment: It is helpful for sure. Well, I see your point. I will think about it.

Comment: One more data point to support this answer: I would not have understood the significance of saying the oath if you hadn't explained that it means you ranked first in your class. The ranking, not the oath, is the important information that you want your CV to convey.

Answer (score 1):

deliver the oath  according to a dialog into the zootopia movie

Comment: I see Zootopia, I hit +1!

Comment: Zootopia is not an authority on the English language. Do you have any reputable references to back up this answer?

Comment: Deliver is fine: The Daily Telegraph  23 Jan 2009 (https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/barackobama/4319001/Barack-Obama-takes-presidential-oath-of-office-for-the-second-time.html) "*Supreme Court Chief Justice John Roberts **delivered the oath** to Mr Obama at the White House on Wednesday night, this time witnessed by a few members of staff and reporters, rather than the 1.8 million on Washington's National Mall who had watched the bungled version the previous day.*"